# laravel routes not working for required parameters

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5.1

I have one route in my `routes.php` like

```
Route::get('{subcat}', array(
  'uses'  => 'frontend\homeController@uploadAd'
))
```

And I found that the above route is effecting my `userlogout` route which is like this.

```
Route::get('userlogout', array(
   'uses' => 'frontend\homeController@userlogout'
));
```

I am getting the `{subcat}` route parameter from the blade view like

```
<a href="{{ subcategoryslug}}">subcategoryname</a>
```

If I  include my `{subcat}` route in `routes.php`, `userlogout` route does not work but, commenting out my `{subcat}`  route or even modifying that route like:

```
 Route::get('something/{subcat}', array(
      'uses'  => 'frontend\homeController@uploadAd'
    ))
```

enable user to log out from the system.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there anything that I can't specify only `route parameter` as my `route name`?

Comment: Have you tried writing the userlogout route BEFORE the subcat route?

Comment: @Amarnasan got it.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can fix this by defining the logout route after the subcat route like this:

```
Route::get('{subcat}', array(
  'uses'  => 'frontend\homeController@uploadAd'
));

Route::get('userlogout', array(
   'uses' => 'frontend\homeController@userlogout'
));
```

This is happening because the first route will match any url with a single parameter. As I know the order of defining routes is important in such cases.

Comment: Its working now..I just wanna ask that what determines the routing order? Is there any specifics?

Comment: I think you mean just the opposite: the "{subcat}" is blocking "userlogout" route

Comment: The routing order is the order in which you specify the route in the routing.php file. The first matching route is the one used.

Comment: I don't think there are any specifics.. it depends from app to app.. your case is a good example when the order is important.. All I can say about this is that I would avoid using routes which could match the same url. I would create specific routes for each action. In your case I would change `{subcat}` to `uploadAd/{subcat}`

Comment: @Amarnasan The way I wrote the answer is the way the routing should be defined. If you inverse these 2 routes then the `userLogout` route will not work anymore because the url will be matched by the second route: `{subcat}`

Comment: @MateiMihai You are saying that the SECOND route is blocking the FIRST route? It doesn't make any sense, man. In case of conflict, the first defined route prevails.

Comment: @Amarnasan I'm saying that the second route will replace the first one.. the reason is that the routes are loaded before execution and are executed from the latest defined to the first ones. The fact that the answer solved the issue is the prove that the answer is correct..

Comment: @MateiMihai The actual answer that solved the issue was my comment, which was posted 3 minutes before your answer, and acknowledged by the poster of the question. Your answer was selected as correct just becaus it "looks" like my comment. Saying just the opposite. Make a minimum research on laravel routing and order.

Comment: I don't like to let incorrect answers on so. I will test this tonight and if your solution is the correct one then I will update my answer and send you the deserved apologize.

Comment: Still waiting for your apology.

Comment: Yes @Amarnasan . I've tested it this weekend and you were right. Sorry.. my mistake